# Mule & Eclipse's WSDL issue

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl, mule

so I have implemented a very simple webservice using eclipse and generated its WSDL using the CXF which is the framework used in Mule as well. However, when I try to publish that same service in Mule using the previously generated WSDL it stops due to something like "BadUsageException: -p invalid character" which is comes from the CXF. I have tried to the java classes from mule using an Axis generated WSDL but no luck with the CXF generated.

Here is my wsdl:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://snippet/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="SnippetService" targetNamespace="http://snippet/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://snippet/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://snippet/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="multiply" type="tns:multiply"/>
<xs:element name="multiplyResponse" type="tns:multiplyResponse"/>
<xs:element name="sum" type="tns:sum"/>
<xs:element name="sumResponse" type="tns:sumResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="sum">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sumResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="multiply">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="multiplyResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="multiplyResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:multiplyResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sumResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:sumResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="sum">
<wsdl:part element="tns:sum" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="multiply">
<wsdl:part element="tns:multiply" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="InterNya">
<wsdl:operation name="sum">
<wsdl:input message="tns:sum" name="sum"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:sumResponse" name="sumResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="multiply">
<wsdl:input message="tns:multiply" name="multiply"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:multiplyResponse" name="multiplyResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="SnippetServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:InterNya">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="sum">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="sum">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="sumResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="multiply">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="multiply">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="multiplyResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SnippetService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:SnippetServiceSoapBinding" name="SnippetPort">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/hassib/services/SnippetPort"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: full error stacktrace, when you get it (on Mule start, when testing the service...), flow config and Mule version.

Comment: Optionally, you can use your WebService's Java Service class if you have. Mule will generate the WSDL for you automatically.
    <cxf:jaxws-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" namespace="http://www.yournamespace.com/" serviceClass="com.mulesoft.soap.SoapService" doc:name="CXF"/>
The SoapService class is annotated with 'at'WebService and methods with 'at'WebMethod.

Comment: Actually it is not an error that I can log. When I created my webservice in eclipse I generated the WSDL which I used again in Mule using the CXF component but it does not generate the necessary classes cause of that In valid Character message.

Comment: @brazo I ll try doind hat yu suggested right now. I just want to have a clientapp that consume a published servicein mule and retrieve the response.

Comment: While what @brazo suggested works I am still required to work with from the WSDL and publish the web services on the Mule side for them to be consimed by a remote client app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your WSDL with the Anypoint Studio July 2014 Release.
It correctly creates the Web Service classes you expect.
I used JavaSE-1.7 and a 3.5.1 Mule engine.

How I did it:
 1. Drag a HTTP endpoint into a new flow
 2. Drag a CXF endpoint behind
 3. Open CXF properties and create the java classes using "Generate from WSDL" at the Service class property

Cheers,
Patrick